# How do I count how many times a specific value has been printed from a list?

Tags: python

I made a simple coin flipper program that, as named flips a coin and prints out the value.

My goal is to **print lots of coin flips and record how many times it lands on heads and how many times it lands on tails.** But obviously I can't because I don't know how to count how many times it lands on a specific value.

```
import random

heads_or_tail = ['heads', 'tail']


def flip_coin():
    flip_coin = random.choice(heads_or_tail)
    print(flip_coin)


for x in range(100):
    flip_coin()
```

Comment: Have you consider storing it in dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried adding a counter variable to keep track of the result instead of printing it? Or just `random.choices([1,0],k=100).count(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `collections` module has a great feature for this called `Counter`:

```
import collections
import random

heads_or_tail = ['heads', 'tail']


def flip_coin():
    flip_coin = random.choice(heads_or_tail)
    return flip_coin

cnt = collections.Counter()
for x in range(100):
    cnt[flip_coin()] += 1
```

Output:

```
>>> cnt
Counter({'tail': 50, 'heads': 50})
```

Alternatively, you could just use a normal `dict` but that requires a bit more boiler-plate code:

```
# Alternatively, you could just use a `dict`
dict_cnt = {}
for x in range(100):
    fc = flip_coin()
    if fc in dict_cnt:
        dict_cnt[fc] += 1
    else:
        dict_cnt[fc] = 1
```

Remember, the most pythonic thing to do is to use libraries that others have perfected - especially from the Python standard library. So, when counting, I would recommend you use `collections.Counter`.

Also, `Counter` has many more cool features you can check out in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

As others have mentioned, you could use a generator passed into the `Counter` constructor, since it is an iterable - this would shorten your code significantly:

```
import collections
import random

flip_gen = (random.choice(['heads', 'tails']) for _ in range(100))
cnt = collections.Counter(flip_gen)

>>> cnt
Counter({'heads': 51, 'tail': 49})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to keep track of the counts of each result is to put them in a dict where each entry corresponds to a particular result.  `collections.defaultdict` is nice for this because it takes care of initializing default values for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

results = defaultdict(int)

for _ in range(100):
    results[random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])] += 1

for result, count in results.items():
    print(f"{result}: {count}")
```

prints something like:

```
heads: 58  
tails: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, It's the beginner friendly solution so far:**

```
import random

head = []
tail = []


def flip_coin():
    for _ in range(100):
        flip_coin = random.choice(['heads', 'tail'])
        if flip_coin == 'heads':
            head.append(flip_coin)
        else:
            tail.append(flip_coin)
    return f'heads: {len(head)}, tails: {len(tail)}'


print(flip_coin())
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution from @Samwise, in case the number of iterations is really high though, I would use generators (range is being evaluated lazily).

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

heads_or_tail = ['heads', 'tail']
d = defaultdict(int)


def flip_coin(iterations):
    for i in range(iterations):
        result_iteration = random.choice(heads_or_tail)
        d[result_iteration] += 1 
        yield result_iteration
```

You can then get the values on demand basis calling **next**() method as here:

```
a = flip_coin(100)
next(a)
next(a)
next(a)
next(a)
```

output :

```
defaultdict(int, {'heads': 1, 'tail': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason why you are forget about the result of each individual Tour i would recommend the other way around. Reasons could be limited memory but i wouldn't expect that;)
Within the package numpy, you also have the function choice.

At the end you can Count with a boolean expression.

```
Result = numpy.random.choice(["head", "tail"], 100)
print(Result)
Numbe_of_head = (Result == "head").sum()
print(Number_of_head)
```

Fürther this solution uses numpy with its iterations.